# FetchXML - record not being return

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have this FetchXML query that returns all the records based off of what business the owner user is in and what probability that the opportunity will be a success.  All of the fields that I am reporting are mandatory and will be filled out. The issue i'm having is that one of my linked accounts - the "new_dealerid" account might not always be filled, if I include this I only get 31 records(all of them have dealers), if I don't I get 32(only new one doesn't have a dealer). So does anyone know how to make this attribute default to an empty string or something if there isnt a related account?

```
<request i:type="b:RetrieveMultipleRequest" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:Parameters xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
                <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <c:key>Query</c:key>
                    <c:value i:type="b:FetchExpression">
                        <b:Query>&lt;fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0" &gt;&#xD;
                            &lt;entity name="opportunity"&gt;&#xD;
                                &lt;attribute name="estimatedvalue" /&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;attribute name="name" /&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;attribute name="new_opportunitytype" /&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;attribute name="new_salesphase" /&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;attribute name="estimatedclosedate" /&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="ownerid"&gt;&#xD;
                    &lt;attribute name="fullname"/&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;/link-entity&gt;
                &lt;link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="new_dealerid"&gt;&#xD;
                    &lt;attribute name="name"/&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;/link-entity&gt;
                &lt;link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="customerid"&gt;&#xD;
                    &lt;attribute name="name"/&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;/link-entity&gt;
                &lt;filter type="and"&gt;
                &lt;condition attribute="salesstagecode" operator="eq" value="'.$prob.'" /&gt;
                &lt;condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="1" /&gt;
                &lt;/filter&gt;
                &lt;link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="ownerid"&gt;&#xD;
                    &lt;link-entity name="businessunit" from="businessunitid" to="businessunitid"&gt;&#xD;
                &lt;filter type="and"&gt;
                    &lt;condition attribute="name" operator="eq" value="'.$bu.'" /&gt;
                &lt;/filter&gt;
                &lt;/link-entity&gt;
                &lt;/link-entity&gt;
                            &lt;/entity&gt;&#xD;
                        &lt;/fetch&gt;</b:Query>
                    </c:value>
                </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            </b:Parameters>
            <b:RequestId i:nil="true"/><b:RequestName>RetrieveMultiple</b:RequestName>
    </request>
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you want to get all 32 records?

In which case you will need to use an outer join.

```
<link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="new_dealerid" link-type="outer">
```

Comment: What ended up working was just using new_dealerid as the attribute.
But that's great to know about link-type in fetchXml, thank you.